# how to play a audio file dynamically in android

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

I have listview with dynamic list of audio files which is stored in a particular folder in sd card when user click a particular file i will get postion in int in onItemClick method i need to create alert dialog box with two buttons first is to play that particular file of that particular position and second is delete that file. how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

register your list with the `onItemClickListener` and inside that method populate a Dialog that have 2 buttons

here is some code :

```
mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            String file_path_in_the_sd_card = YOURADAPTER.getFilePathAtPosition(position);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Option")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Play", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           //start the activity the will play the song and provide the path to it 

                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           //make a code that will delete the file maybe like this 
                           File file = new File(file_path_in_sd_card);
                           file.delete();

                           //remove it aslo from your adapter 

                           myadpter.removeFile(poistion);
                           myadpater.notifyDataSetChange();

                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();




}
```

this code to help you think how to do that job it not a complete example .

Comment: String file_path_in_the_sd_card = YOURADAPTER.getFilePathAtPosition(position); this line giving me error..

Comment: you should implement this method in your adapter , maybe if post your adapter code i will do something that works fine to you regards

Comment: in YOURADAPTER i m passing my adapter's object but it is giving me error

Comment: your adapter doesnot have this method you should define it , post your adapter code

Comment: return the file path for that view item :)